Cylinder rotation in React-three-fiber
I can't make the cylinder rotate straight.
I wan't to create rotating coin with react-three-js. I decided to use low height cylinder geometry for that. To achieve the coin-like shape, I had to rotate the cylinder to be up side facing the screen using initial rotation on z-axis. When I am applying y axis rotation to it - it rotates, but appear wobbly and not centered as I expect the coin rotation to be. It seems to be rolling around and not spinning, it is seen on the attached GIF.
Here is the preview: GIF of the spinning coin
Here is my code:
import { Canvas, useFrame } from "@react-three/fiber";
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import * as THREE from 'three';

type CoinType = {};

const Coin: React.FC<CoinType> = () => {
  const ref = useRef<THREE.Mesh>(null);

  useFrame((state, delta) => {
    if (ref.current) {
      ref.current.rotation.y += 4 * delta;
    }
  });

  return (
    <>
      <spotLight
        position={[10, 10, 10]}
        angle={0.15}
        penumbra={1}
        decay={0}
        intensity={Math.PI}
      />
      <directionalLight position={[0, 0, 3]} />
      <mesh ref={ref} position={[0, 0, 0]} rotation={[0, 0, Math.PI / 2]}>
        <cylinderGeometry args={[2, 2, 0.3, 128]} />
        <meshStandardMaterial color={"#D2E9FB"} />
      </mesh>
    </>
  );
};

export default Coin;


Where is that image? What is mean “wobbly”, pivot issue?

I attached it to the question. Sorry, it didn't attach on the first try. Here it is:  https://i.sstatic.net/IFhMzGWk.gif I think wobbly is not the best word to describe it, it is just kind of rolling around instead of spinning on one place.

Thank you, it works for the codepen and for codesandbox  - https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-three-fiber-rotation-forked-kcvrxh even with my code, but on my development machine, MacOS, on localhost, it still does not spin right and has the same behavior. :(

It turned out that both my code and quaternion code example work fine, the issue was with mesh scaling and camera position and canvas size. I found out that the smaller cylynder is, the more straight it spinns. I used  component to find out the position of the cylinder, adjusted  size and cylinder size, zoomed the camera and the coin started spinning straight.
